# Iteration in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, iteration

I am taking values from a Modal using below code.

```
<Modal :show="showModal" @hide="showModal = false" @submitted_job_data ="data_submitted"></Modal>
```

My Vue.js code is like below

```
<script>
  import Modal from './Modal';
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        showModal: false,
        jobs: [],
      }
    },
    components: { Modal },
    methods: {
      data_submitted(value) {
        this.jobs.push(value);
        console.log(Object.values(this.jobs)); 
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

I am iterating vales like below

```
<tbody>
   <tr v-for="job in jobs" :key="job.id">
    <td>
     {{ job[0] }}
    </td>
    <td>
     {{ job[1] }}
    </td>
    <td>
     {{ job[2] }}
    </td>
    <td>
     {{ job[3] }}
    </td>
    <td>
     {{ job[4] }}
     </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

I am getting console result like below

[image]

Why I am getting `Getter & Setter` instead of value ?

Comment: What is the problem exactly? How does what you want to achieve differ from what you currently have?

Comment: Thanks @skirtle. Why I am getting `Getter & Setter` instead of value ?

Comment: `Object.values()` should be apply on `objects` not on `arrays`, i mean `jobs is a array`.

Answer (score 2):

Vue rewrites object properties to use a getter and setter so it can track when they are accessed.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

If you expand the object in the console you'll still be able to access the underlying value. The value isn't shown automatically because calling the getter could have side-effects.

As far as your other code is concerned you don't need to worry about the getter and setter, just use the objects like you normally would. e.g.:

```html
<td>{{ job.company_name }}</td>
```

Comment: Thanks @skirtle for your reply. Could you please say how can I iterate over the objects ?

Comment: @abuabu Not sure I understand--you already *are* iterating over the objects. Which objects are you talking about?

Comment: Thanks @DaveNewton. I am not getting any output in browser while iterating.

Comment: @abuabu I have updated my answer with a concrete example of outputting a value.

Comment: Thanks @skirtle. I tried your solution before posting this question but it is not working. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The `v-for` loop you do in your Template works and iterates the object, but the elements below are not correct. It should look like this:

```
<tr v-for="job in jobs">
  <td :key="job.id">
   {{ job.company_name }}
  </td>
</tr>
```

The getters and setters don't matter to you, you can ignore them and access the values in the object like usual: `{{ job.company_name }}`. It's an internal thing Vue does.

Working example:
https://codepen.io/reynicke/pen/PMyLBb